# Происхождение слов "первый" и "второй"

Tags: числительные

Порядковые числительные образуются от количественных. То есть, "третий" - от "три", "десятый" - от "десять" и т.д.
Но из этого ряда совершенно выбиваются слова "первый" и "второй". "Второй", как я понимаю, родственен слову "повторять", "повтор", а вот как быть со словом "первый"? И почему вообще они полностью отличаются от всех остальных числительных?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первый и второй, передний и другой, следующий далее.

Числительное  "первый" имеет и.-е корень per со значением "перед, передний", о.-с. основа pьrvъ.

Числительное "второй" также восходит к и.-е. основе, но здесь есть разные мнения. Одни лингвисты считают, что родственным словом является др.-инд. anteros  - другой. Черных предполагает, что, скорее, это vitaram  - следующий далее, дальнейший.

Comment: Насчёт "второго" действительно какая-то неясность . "Второй" совпадает только в русском и болгарском . В остальных славянских языках типа , как в украинском , - "другий" .

Comment: Есть в украинском и "вторий", "втора", и этимологический словарь украинского (какой у меня есть под рукой, так сказать) тоже ведёт путь от vitaram.

Answer (score 3):

"Первый" перекликается с наречием "перво", имеющим значение "начало". Хотя, нельзя точно утверждать, какое из слов первично. Так же существуют схожие индийские слова, имеющие значение "прежний"/"изначальный" (pū́rvas).

Этимологию слова "второй" так же можно соотнести с индийским "vítaras" (ведущий далее). Помимо этого, стоит упомянуть о созвучии слова "второй" с "торой". "В торе" или, переводя на русский, "в законе/учении". Подобная отсылка может иметь как философский, так и религиозный подтекст, хотя, нужно упомянуть, что это рассуждения, а не 100% установленный факт.

Отличие первых двух чисел от последующих полагаю так же искать в религиозно-философском контексте. Цифры имели огромное значение для народов древности, в особенности для индусов (если мы берём версию о индийских корнях как заслуживающую доверия). Обосновывать значимость отличительных названий первых двух чисел можно до бесконечности: "дуальность мира: материальное и духовное", "женские и мужские начала", "аллегория сотворения" -- здесь богатая почва для спекуляций. Достоверно, вам, вероятно, уже не ответит никто.

Comment: При чём тут "дуальность" и прочие философствования? Весь смысл "выделения" этих числительных определила Аллегрова ("..кто у нас не первый, тот у нас второй.."). "До-арифметическое" противопоставление "первый - не первый".  
Отсылка к Торе - и вовсе является попыткой "впихнуть невпихуемое".

Comment: Это не Аллегрова пела, а Распутина. А насчет высоких материй типа дуальности и Торы, то они тут действительно абсолютно неуместны.

Answer (score 3):

Сразу скажу, я не филолог, но есть одна очень интересная идея.

Сейчас сохранилась, пожалуй, пара слов с корнем "тор": проторенный, затор.
Торить - делать дорогу "проходимой", "тор" что-то вроде "след" или "шаг". Ну или "путь".
вторить, повторять, второй - "идущий по следу".

Answer (score 1):

Во фригийском зарегистрировано [witoran] "второй", так что Черных, видимо, ближе к истине.
Ну и метафора переть-торить, вроде, неплохо смотрится в качестве гипотезы о природе первого и второго.

Answer (score 0):

Со словом "первый" словари разобрались правильно, это родич санскритскому "pUrva" - начальный, предшествующий, первый
http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=purva&direct=se&anz=100
А со словом "второй" они ошибаются: корень "tar" они берут правильно, а приставку - нет, везде у них то "antaras", то "vitaram", хотя должна быть приставка "ut" - "uttara" - следующий, последующий, позднейший
http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=uttara&direct=se&anz=100

Answer (score -3):

Для ответа на данный вопрос нужно хорошо знать законы и правила по которым в древности создавались слова. Каждая буква в древности обозначала число. Буква "В" в частности обозначала число 2. От нее образовывались однокоренные с этим числом (буквой) слова.
Для обозначения порядкового номера 2=В добавляется слово ТОР ( תור ), означающее очередь, положение в очереди (это иврит), отсюда 2 + очередь = В+Тор = Второй.
От буквы В=2 образуется также слово д+Ва. Поэтому слова дВа и Второй - это однокоренные слова с общим корнем из одной буквы "В", обозначающей число 2.
Вообще говоря, в древности существовало правило, по которому все слова должны создаваться из чисел, в роли которых изначально выступали буквы. Каждая буква в древности обозначала число.
А = 1
В = 2
З = 3
и т.д.

Comment: "Законы и правила по которым в древности создавались слова". Где Вы нашли такие законы? Подобные заявления желательно подкреплять ссылками на источник информации.

Comment: К сожалению здесь невозможно загрузить скрины из древних книг. Но вы можете найти любую древнюю книгу (лучше на иврите, где это эти законы описаны) и открыть первую страницу с содержанием. И тут же обнаружите все эти законы в колонке с номером страницы. Там увидите алгоритм закона создания слов обозначающих числа. Страница 1 там обозначена как страница А. Страница 2 будет В. Страница 3 может обозначаться буквами З, Г, С в зависимости от языка. Стр 4 обозначается буквой Д. Страница 5 буквой Е. Для обозначения страницы 9 будут сложены буквы Д+Е(4+5=9). Для числа 10 буквы Д+Е+с+Ять(4+5 с +1=10)

Comment: Андрей, пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что вы можете загрузить любое изображение, в том числе фотографию «древних книг».